# Connection Refused from NextJS API (Incremental Static Regeneration calls)

Tags: node.js, next.js

I set up my NodeJS server to make a post request every time a user adds a product to perform incremental static regeneration. I have my NextJS running on port 3000 and NodeJS running on 3001

This is my /api/revalidate file in my NextJS application:

```
async function handleRevalidate(req, res) {
  console.log("/api/revalidate received:", req.body);
  const event = req.body;
  if (event.model === "product") {
    const id = event.entry.id;
    await Promise.all([res.revalidate("/"), res.revalidate(`/products/${id}`)]);
    console.log("revalidated product", id);
  }
  res.status(204).end();
}

export default handleRevalidate;
```

This is my NodeJS controller that's making the request to the NextJS's /api/revalidate:

```
const addProduct = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const query = mysql2.format("INSERT INTO products VALUES ?", [
      [Object.values(req.body)],
    ]);
    const [resData, _] = await db.execute(query);
    console.log(resData);
    await axios.post("http://localhost:3000/api/revalidate", {
      model: "product",
      entry: {
        id: req.body.id,
        title: req.body.title,
        description: req.body.description,
        price: req.body.price,
      },
    });
    res.status(201).send("Product Added");
    console.log(query);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
module.exports = addProduct
```

The NodeJS and Next App interacts fine in Next Dev mode, but when I build the Next App and start it in production mode, this connect error occurs.

```
  AxiosError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:3000
    at AxiosError.from (/Users/aiden/Documents/theavocado_backend/node_modules/axios/dist/node/axios.cjs:789:14)
    at RedirectableRequest.handleRequestError (/Users/aiden/Documents/theavocado_backend/node_modules/axios/dist/node/axios.cjs:2744:25)
    at RedirectableRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at eventHandlers.<computed> (/Users/aiden/Documents/theavocado_backend/node_modules/follow-redirects/index.js:14:24)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:490:9)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  port: 3000,
  address: '::1',
  syscall: 'connect',
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: -61,
  config: {
    transitional: {
      silentJSONParsing: true,
      forcedJSONParsing: true,
      clarifyTimeoutError: false
    },
    adapter: [ 'xhr', 'http' ],
    transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
    transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
    timeout: 0,
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    maxContentLength: -1,
    maxBodyLength: -1,
    env: { FormData: [Function], Blob: [class Blob] },
    validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
    headers: AxiosHeaders {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'User-Agent': 'axios/1.2.2',
      'Content-Length': '118',
      'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, compress, deflate, br'
    },
    method: 'post',
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/revalidate',
    data: '{"model":"product","entry":{"id":87663301,"title":"KL Light","description":"Very energy efficient light.","price":12}}'
  },
  request: <ref *1> Writable {
    _writableState: WritableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      finalCalled: false,
      needDrain: false,
      ending: false,
      ended: false,
      finished: false,
      destroyed: false,
      decodeStrings: true,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      length: 0,
      writing: false,
      corked: 0,
      sync: true,
      bufferProcessing: false,
      onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
      writecb: null,
      writelen: 0,
      afterWriteTickInfo: null,
      buffered: [],
      bufferedIndex: 0,
      allBuffers: true,
      allNoop: true,
      pendingcb: 0,
      constructed: true,
      prefinished: false,
      errorEmitted: false,
      emitClose: true,
      autoDestroy: true,
      errored: null,
      closed: false,
      closeEmitted: false,
      [Symbol(kOnFinished)]: []
    },
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      response: [Function: handleResponse],
      error: [Function: handleRequestError],
      socket: [Function: handleRequestSocket]
    },
    _eventsCount: 3,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    _options: {
      maxRedirects: 21,
      maxBodyLength: Infinity,
      protocol: 'http:',
      path: '/api/revalidate',
      method: 'POST',
      headers: [Object: null prototype],
      agents: [Object],
      auth: undefined,
      beforeRedirect: [Function: dispatchBeforeRedirect],
      beforeRedirects: [Object],
      hostname: 'localhost',
      port: '3000',
      agent: undefined,
      nativeProtocols: [Object],
      pathname: '/api/revalidate'
    },
    _ended: false,
    _ending: true,
    _redirectCount: 0,
    _redirects: [],
    _requestBodyLength: 118,
    _requestBodyBuffers: [ [Object] ],
    _onNativeResponse: [Function (anonymous)],
    _currentRequest: ClientRequest {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 7,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      outputData: [],
      outputSize: 0,
      writable: true,
      destroyed: false,
      _last: false,
      chunkedEncoding: false,
      shouldKeepAlive: true,
      maxRequestsOnConnectionReached: false,
      _defaultKeepAlive: true,
      useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
      sendDate: false,
      _removedConnection: false,
      _removedContLen: false,
      _removedTE: false,
      strictContentLength: false,
      _contentLength: '118',
      _hasBody: true,
      _trailer: '',
      finished: false,
      _headerSent: true,
      _closed: false,
      socket: [Socket],
      _header: 'POST /api/revalidate HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
        'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
        'Content-Type: application/json\r\n' +
        'User-Agent: axios/1.2.2\r\n' +
        'Content-Length: 118\r\n' +
        'Accept-Encoding: gzip, compress, deflate, br\r\n' +
        'Host: localhost:3000\r\n' +
        'Connection: keep-alive\r\n' +
        '\r\n',
      _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
      _onPendingData: [Function: nop],
      agent: [Agent],
      socketPath: undefined,
      method: 'POST',
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      path: '/api/revalidate',
      _ended: false,
      res: null,
      aborted: false,
      timeoutCb: [Function: emitRequestTimeout],
      upgradeOrConnect: false,
      parser: null,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      reusedSocket: false,
      host: 'localhost',
      protocol: 'http:',
      _redirectable: [Circular *1],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kEndCalled)]: false,
      [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
      [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype],
      [Symbol(errored)]: null,
      [Symbol(kUniqueHeaders)]: null
    },
    _currentUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/api/revalidate',
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  },
  cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:3000
      at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1471:16) {
    errno: -61,
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    syscall: 'connect',
    address: '::1',
    port: 3000
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There was no problem with the NextJS part, but with my NodeJS backend. It is not okay to use http://localhost:3000, but instead have to use http://127.0.0.1:3000. So by changing my NodeJS file to:

```
const addProduct = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const query = mysql2.format("INSERT INTO products VALUES ?", [
      [Object.values(req.body)],
    ]);
    const [resData, _] = await db.execute(query);
    console.log(resData);
    await axios.post("http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/revalidate", {
      model: "product",
      entry: {
        id: req.body.id,
        title: req.body.title,
        description: req.body.description,
        price: req.body.price,
      },
    });
    res.status(201).send("Product Added");
    console.log(query);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
module.exports = addProduct
```

everything will work as expected.